# Search AWS CloudWatch Logs with special character in JSON property name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

We use AWS CloudWatch Logs to debug our services running on AWS, and a number of the property names in our logs use colons as delimiters, but we can't figure out how to search using these property names.

Here's an example of a log:

```
{
  "Counts": {
    "RouteHandler:GetCookies": {
      "value": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Using the console, I've tried a query like this:

```
{ $.Counts.RouteHandler:GetCookies.value = 1 }
```

Of course, special characters often have specific uses in query languages and otherwise, so I've try to escape it somehow.

```
{ $.Counts.RouteHandler\:GetCookies.value = 1 }
// JavaScript inspired
{ $.Counts["RouteHandler:GetCookies"].value = 1 }
// Special character removed
{ $.Counts.RouteHandlerGetCookies.value = 1 }
```

Nothing I could come up with worked, and maybe it's just not possible. [The docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html) don't seem to address this type of scenario.

Anyone know how to search JSON logs where properties contain special characters, or know definitively whether or not this is supported?

In new work, we're going to use a different delimiter, but we're not going to go back and change it everywhere.

Comment: Never seen that one before.  One thing we found was that it sometimes tokenizes as numerics in weird places.  The hex string 0101fdb913 can only be found in the logs if you omit the leading 0.

Answer (score 9):

At the time of writing, this is not possible. The only workaround would be to use the non-JSON syntax and search for the exact string. The following filter:

```
"\"RouteHandler:GetCookies\": {\"value\": 1}"
```

will match this log event:

```
{"Counts": {"RouteHandler:GetCookies": {"value": 1}}}
```

Obviously the downside is that whitespace and position matter.

Answer (score 7):

This still isn't possible to do with CloudWatch Logs, but you can do this with CloudWatch Logs Insights, which is better suited for working with structured logging anyway. Logs Insights will automatically discover fields in your JSON logging and provides a powerful query language with builtin commands and functions.

In the query you simply quote the property name in backticks, for example:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter `Counts.RouteHandler:GetCookies.value` = 1
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html#CWL_QuerySyntax-commnds):

> You must surround log fields named in queries that include characters other than the `@` symbol, period (`.`), and non-alphanumeric characters in backtick keys (`` ` ``). For example, the log field `foo-bar` must be enclosed in backticks (`` `foo-bar` ``) because it contains a non-alphanumeric character, the hyphen (`-`).